# No height information in GoogleEarth paths?

Tags: google-earth

I created a path in Google Earth, but when I outputted the data in KML format the lat/lon/altitude records were as follows:

> 65.89812717287285,31.90027330527765,0 65.92477577515706,31.9037649702952,0 65.96928881819234,31.94668549963917,0 65.99250268257912,32.06014077590489,0 65.98887339773842,32.07623793179312,0 66.02510050148277,32.08990031907214,0 66.04934420340139,32.11057291247619,0 66.04383792983393,32.13579588153775,0 66.04017675736542,32.15243094141274,0 66.04946083542221,32.17672733087856,0 66.05707893538859,32.2069088934152,0 66.06555640478098,32.2241185351639,0 66.08010755258314,32.24649523809578,0 66.08631779035734,32.26902880901822,0 66.08738132747307,32.28210046448878,0 66.09448502585732,32.3106520210064,0 66.08113635056179,32.37681697934688,0

The heights are all listed as zeroes. I need the altitudes. Is there a way to get the altitudes in the KML?

I have no Terrain option in my layers panel. I have 3D rendering turned on:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the `Terrain` under `Layers Panel` is checked first before drawing the path to get the `Z` elevation, as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: There is no terrain option in my layers panel. I have updated my question to show this. I am using Google Earth version 7.1.

Comment: I am using Google Earth Pro version 7.1.2.2041, which is free also.